# Error working with oop (classes)

Tags: ruby

I just started with `ruby`, and just started learning `oop` today, after making a class, I am trying to print to console yet I keep getting this error. Does anyone know what's wrong?

> undefined method `set_brand_name=' for # (NoMethodError)

Here is the code causing this error:

```
class Laptop

    def set_brand_name(brand_name)
        @brand = brand_name
    end

    def get_brand_name
        return @brand
    end

    def set_color(color)
        @color = color
    end

    def get_color
        return @color
    end

    def set_processor(processor)
        @processor = processor
    end

    def get_processor
        return @processor
    end

    def set_storage(hard_drive)
        @storage = hard_drive
    end

    def get_storage
        return @storage
    end

    def set_memory(ram)
        @memory = ram
    end

    def get_memory
        return @memory
    end
end

my_laptop = Laptop.new
my_laptop.set_brand_name = "HP"
my_laptop.set_processor = 'i7-4700k'
my_laptop.set_memory = '16gb'
my_laptop.set_storage = '750gb'
my_laptop.set_color = 'Silver'

brand = my_laptop.get_brand_name
color = my_laptop.get_color
processor = my_laptop.get_processor
memory = my_laptop.get_memory
storage = my_laptop.get_storage
```

This should output the message:

> """The Laptop I want is an #{brand}, it has a #{processor}, 
>       #{memory} of ram, a #{storage}, and it #{color}!!!"""

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The error message is clear. Look at how you define the method `set_brand_name` and then look at how you call it. Do you see the difference? It's useful to practice going through this process as you learn. Also, 'Object Oriented Programming' is usually shortened to 'OOP', not 'OPP'.

Comment: Thanks for the swift response Tim! I see it now.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are not calling the method names as you've defined them.  You defined `set_brand_name` without an equal sign so use:

```
my_laptop.set_brand_name("HP")
```

I would simply the getters and setters like so:

```
class Laptop
  def brand_name=(brand_name)
    @brand_name = brand_name
  end

  def brand_name
    @brand_name
  end
end
```

Or even better:

```
class Laptop
  attr_accessor :brand_name
end
```

Then you can use it the same way:

```
my_laptop = Laptop.new
my_laptop.brand_name = "HP"
puts my_laptop.brand_name # => "HP"
```

Answer (score 1):

In line 45, you are calling the method `set_brand_name=`, but your `Laptop` class doesn't have a method with that name. You need to either call the method which you *do* have (`set_brand_name`), or rename the `set_brand_name` method to `set_brand_name=`.

Note that neither of those two is idiomatic, though. Idiomatically, the method should be named `brand_name=` (without the `set_` prefix, the "setting" part is already implied by the `=` sign), and you shouldn't define it manually, but programmatically using the `Module#attr_writer` method.

Your entire code can be condensed to:

```
Laptop = Struct.new(:brand_name, :color, :processor, :storage, :memory)

my_laptop = Laptop.new('HP', 'Silver', 'i7-4700k', '750gb', '16gb')

brand     = my_laptop.brand_name
color     = my_laptop.color
processor = my_laptop.processor
memory    = my_laptop.memory
storage   = my_laptop.storage

puts "The Laptop I want is an #{brand}, it has a #{processor}, #{memory} of ram, a #{storage}, and it's #{color}!!!"
```

Answer (score 1):

Your setter methods are defined incorrectly.

Here's your definition of the `set_brand_name` method:

```
def set_brand_name(brand_name)
    @brand = brand_name
end
```

And here's how you're calling it:

```
my_laptop.set_brand_name = "HP"
```

You're calling the method incorrectly. If you'd like to keep your definition, you should be calling it like this:

```
my_laptop.set_brand_name("HP")
```

Or, if you'd like to use the equals sign, you should define your method like this:

```
def set_brand_name=(brand_name)
    @brand = brand_name
end
```

Notice the equals in the method definition? You're required to use it when you want the setter to look like a regular assignment.

However, for most trivial cases you don't need to define getters and setters manually. You can just use `attr_accessor` on the class and pass it the properties you want to define. Here's what your class would look like with `attr_accessor`:

```
class Laptop    
   attr_accessor: :brand_name, :color, :processor, :storage, :memory
end

my_laptop = Laptop.new
my_laptop.brand_name = "HP"
my_laptop.processor = 'i7-4700k'
my_laptop.memory = '16gb'
my_laptop.storage = '750gb'
my_laptop.color = 'Silver'

brand = my_laptop.brand_name
color = my_laptop.color
processor = my_laptop.processor
memory = my_laptop.memory
storage = my_laptop.storage

puts """The Laptop I want is an #{brand}, it has a #{processor}, 
#{memory} of ram, a #{storage}, and it #{color}!!!"""
```

I encourage you to try it.

Comment: Man, thats so much cleaner! Thanks Jorge, I will try that.